# Java: ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, arrays

I've got the following Java code:

```
public void varsInvullen(String tempTekst){
        int i,aantalVraagtekens = 0;
        String ingevuldeParameter;

        for(i= 0; tempTekst.length() > i; i++){
            if(tempTekst.charAt(i) == '?'){
                aantalVraagtekens++;
                System.out.println(aantalVraagtekens);
                }
            }

        String[] variables1 = new String[aantalVraagtekens+1];
        String[] tempTekst2 = tempTekst.split("\\s+");

        for(i = 0; tempTekst2.length > i; i++){
            if(tempTekst2[i].charAt(0) == '?'){

                variables1[i] = tempTekst2[i];
                if(!variables1[i].equals("null")){
                    System.out.println("Invoer voor parameter: "+variables1[i]+" >>>");
                    ingevuldeParameter = Input.readString();

                    tempTekst = tempTekst.replace(variables1[i],ingevuldeParameter);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("De volledig ingevulde template:");
        System.out.println(tempTekst);
    }
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
        at Mailmatcher.varsInvullen(Mailmatcher.java:68)
        at Mailmatcher.personaliseren(Mailmatcher.java:90)
        at Mailmatcher.menu(Mailmatcher.java:29)
        at Mailmatcher.main(Mailmatcher.java:131)
```

I know this error mean that my array is too small, but it isn't, because if i play around with `System.out.println(variables1.length);`in different places, it always shows the array to be te right size..

Don't know if it's clear what i mean, if you need additional information, just ask.

Thank you!

Comment: And which line exactly is line 68? I feel it may have something to do with the  `i++;` inside the for loop. Should this really be there?

Comment: variables1[i] = tempTekst2[i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variables1` has a length equal to the number of question marks in `tempTekst` + 1. `tempTekst2` is an array made from splitting `tempTekst` on one or more whitespace characters. You then loop using the length of `tempTekst2` which may be larger than `variables1` if `tempTekst` has more whitespace-separated words than question marks.

For example, if your input string is `"Do we ? count ? only ? blue ? cars ?"` then the length of `variables1` will be 6. `tempTekst2` will be `{"Do", "we", "?", "count", "?", "only", "?", "blue", "?", "cars", "?"}` When you loop using the length of `tempTekst2` you will loop 11 times. So when you hit the 1st question mark `i` will equal 2. When you hit the last question mark `i` will equal 10. When you try to set `variables1[10]` = whatever text is input you get the exception because the size of `variables1` is only 6.

Comment: that's what I ment to do with the code, i don't think i'm getting you, could you be more specific please?

Comment: Your code will only work if the number of "words" resulting from splitting `tempTekst` is less than or equal to the number of question marks the string contains + 1.

Comment: oooh, I see now, that basically means that my code will never work this way :p I'll take a look at it and get back to you guys if I find a solution

Comment: Instead of looping over each word in `tempTekst2` just loop from 0 to the number of question marks you counted.

Comment: if i do that, (repalcing tempTekst2.length with aantalVraagtekens), it let's me fill in one or two parameters, and then it just jumps out of the loop

Comment: You'll have to do some debugging and see what's going on. Without knowing your input data I can't guess at what's going wrong.

Answer (score -2):

You want length()-1 in your for loops.  Java lists/arrays are zero indexed so while the length might be X the last element is at X-1

Comment: Check that second for loop, too.  that middle condition looks a bit wonky.  Also, when putting up stacktraces and code snippets, it's helpful to tell which line in the trace matches which line in the snippet so we know where to look.

Comment: tried length-1 on both, but still, the same result, i'll edit my post

Comment: This is definitely not a zero-indexing issue. Note that what he's doing isn't any different from `for (int i = 0; i < tempTekst.length; i++)` and `for (int i = 0; i < tempTekst2.length; i++)`